# How can i search for a single id if i save it in array in one field in laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

[See the image please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4Bc2.png)

I am saving admission classes fields data in array/json encode format,but i want to search all data where id is 7 from admission classes. how can i do it in larave.please guide and see the image above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So since JSON is text, you can search like so:

```
Model::where('field', 'like', '%7%')->get();
```

Comment: $items= SchoolDetails::orderBy('id','desc')->where('admission_classes', 'like', '%id:$class%')->where('city',$city)->paginate(40);   not working

Comment: Use double quotes: 

->where('admission_classes', 'like', "%id:$class%")

Comment: So I just saw your image and you've got an array 

->where('admission_classes', 'like', "%$class%")

That should do.

Comment: Done as you said , but not working.. here is my function            public function schoollist($class='', $city='')

        {

        $items= SchoolDetails::orderBy('id','desc')->where('admission_classes', 'like', "%id:$class%")->where('city',$city)->paginate(40);
print_r($items);
exit();
          return view('frontend.schools.schools_list',compact('active_class','items'));

        }

Comment: SchoolDetails::orderBy('id','desc')->where('admission_classes', 'like', "%$class%")->where('city',$city)->paginate(40);

Comment: I initially assumed data like "{id:7, ...}" but you have ["7", ...].

Comment: I am able to search , thanks you soo much..

Comment: You're welcome... Can you please mark as the answer?

Comment: one more issue found can you help me ??

Comment: OK. Whats the issue?

Comment: when i search for id 1 it also gives me the result where the value is 11 or 12 , and when i search for value 7 it give me all the result where id is 27 or 77

Comment: Oh... I see. Change your query to include the delimiters...

where('admission_classes', 'like', "%,\"{$class}\",%");

Comment: Thank you soo much..sir